# Defining html special characters as an entity or element to be replaced by a Unicode character in XSD

Tags: html, unicode, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

I have a XML doc with a bunch of html special character encoding throughout. These need to be switched over to a Unicode set in order to display correctly in Access, where I'm importing them to.

I managed to do this simply by opening notepad and replacing the text, which worked. But as this data is volatile I was hoping there was some way I'd be able to define the characters as entities/elements in an XSD schema that would automatically replace the hmtl code as it Unicode equivalent.
So:

```
&ndash;
```

Automatically would become:

```
&#x2013;
```

I thought something as simple as the below would work; but had no luck.

Comment: XSD is for schema validation, you're confused.

Comment: Oh... So that simply not possible then. Thanks/

Answer (score 1):

Add a DTD that contains the HTML entities to the input document, then run `xmllint --loaddtd --noent input.xml`. The program ships with `libxml2-tools`. Demo:

```
❯ cat so58504198.xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<lol>&ndash;</lol>
❯ xmllint --loaddtd --noent so58504198.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<lol>&#x2013;</lol>
❯ xmllint --loaddtd --noent --dropdtd so58504198.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lol>&#x2013;</lol>
```